# Update Existing Alias via Command Line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have an alias set in my .bashrc

`ssh_iggy='ssh bheng@192.155.111.111 -p 2022'`

I want to update my alias to

`ssh_iggy='ssh bheng@192.155.111.111 -p 2022; clear'`

Rather than open up the `.bashrc` file, and modify it.

**I'm wondering if there's a way that I can achieve this via a command line.**

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i  "/ssh_iggy/s/'$/;clear'/"  bash.rc
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do not want the .bashrc changed, you can append `clear` to the existing alias with

```
alias ssh_iggy=$(alias ssh_iggy | sed "s/.*='\(.*\)'$/\1;clear/")
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly try Following:

```
sed -i '/ssh_iggy/d' .bashrc ;  echo "ssh_iggy='ssh bheng@192.155.111.111 -p 2022; clear" >> .bashrc
```

Change ur .bashrc path if required